# Ошибка в цикле for с использованием структур

Tags: c++, циклы, for

Программа проверяет значения item[].name типа string от 1-го до 100-го.
Если предмета нет (item[num].name == “”), то начинается цикл, ищущий следующий существующий предмет и заменяет отсутствующий на него.

(Переменная m служит для перебора предметов, пока не будет найден существующий.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct STRname
{
    string name;
};
int main()
{
    STRname item[100];
    item[1].name = "text1";
    item[10].name = "text2";
    int m;


    for (int num = 1; num < 100; num++)
    {
        m = num;
        if (item[num].name == "") // найдено отсутствие предмета
        {
            for (item[m].name; item[m].name == ""; m++) {}
            //предмет под номером m - существует
            item[num].name = item[m].name; //заменяет на существующий
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Либо нет ограничителя и я не знаю как его добавить, либо ошибка в логике цикла.
При запуске крашится и пишется ошибка:

> Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x665F391E (vcruntime140d.dll) в
> Test.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу
> 0x65168A77.

Comment: Начните проверять выход за пределы массива.

Comment: как это сделать? я бы хотел ввести if(item[100].name =="end") выход из цикла; , чтобы не было выхода, но не знаю как и куда его вписать

Comment: При `m >= 11` все оставшиеся строки в массиве будут пустыми, т.е. условие `item[m].name == ""` будет истенно всегда и в какой-то момент `m` станет больше 100 и при очередной проверке `item[m].name == ""` произойдёт выход за пределы массива. Как минимум можно проверять границы массива в цикле: `m < 100 && item[m].name == ""`. Но тогда и строку `item[num].name = item[m].name;` также нужно будет завернуть в условие, чтобы не копировать пустую строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал в цикле прохода поиска элемента с первым непустым именем добавить условие `m < 100` — так цикл остановится в пределах массива и не выдаст ошибку. Затем нужно после этого цикла проверить, не превысило ли m 100 — для этого пишем условный оператор и проверяем данное условие. Если оно соблюдается, то элемент под номером `m` действительно имеет некоторое непустое имя, значит, мы можем совершить присваивание.

Вот кусок кода, если что:

```cpp
if (item[num].name == "") // найдено отсутствие предмета
{
    cout << m << endl;
    for (; m < 100 && item[m].name == ""; m++) {}
    //предмет под номером m - существует
    if (m < 100) { // если m осталось меньше 100
                   // (т.е. есть существ. элемент под номером m)
        item[num] = item[m];
        item[m].name = ""; //замена и удаление использованного предмета
    }
}
```